# Add a % sign after a regular Wordpress counter

Tags: wordpress

How can I add a % sign after a digit on the counter element on a Wordpress template.

The current code is as follows:

[counter type="zero" box="no" position="center" separator="no" digit="31" font_color="#20d279" text="more productivity" ordinal_suffix="$counter"]

Comment: And what is this counter shortcode? It comes with any plugin or theme? Or is it your own custom shortcode?

Comment: It comes with the theme. I am using a template called Bridge and the counter was added as a regular element on the WPBakery Page Builder which is a Backend Editor.